# Web.stdout logs stopping randomly on Amazon linux

Tags: amazon-ec2, systemd, amazon-linux-2, systemd-journald

My EC2 insurance is started by beanstalk and my logging just stops randomly after successfully loghing for a few minutes. But I know my app is still running due to database entries.

I restarted journald using `systemctl restart systemd-journald` and that seems to start the logging again.

What can I do to investigate this further?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was due to my app being python based and python automatically buffers stdout and stderr streams. I started the app using PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 before the command and now logs stream in real time